# how to access structure variables value without calling on the variables name before the member?

Tags: c++, struct

How do use a structure variables value inside a structure member without calling on the structure variables name but only using the member of that structure and a global variable (string)? the idea is that i set the global variables value to the structure variables name and then just doing `.structM` after that variable kinda like this: `global.structM` with `global` being the global variable.

i tried this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
string global = "structV";
struct{
  int structM;
}structV;
int main() {
  structV.structM = 100;
  cout << structV.structM << endl << endl;
  cout << global.structM << endl << endl;
  
}
```

but of course the solution won't be that simple. `cout << global.value << endl << endl;` appered as a error. i inatialy thought that maybe, just maybe, it would work. My hopes were low and sure enough, it didn't work. it just said that there were, `no member named "structM" in std::basic_string<char>`. So, is there a way to solve this?

Comment: If you must, you could use a pointer to a struct, but honestly what you want to do doesn't make much sense to me and I feel it just makes your code harder to read, understand, and work with.

Comment: you declared `global` to be a string. You can't add any members to `global`, so `std::string` doesn't have a `structM` field.

Comment: i want it to that even if i have 3 or more stuct variables, i would still be able to use `global` by setting the name of those variables to `global`s value

Comment: That sounds reasonable, but `global` MUST be the correct type. You cannot easily change types at runtime. They are baked in when the program is compiled.

Comment: I recommend not using global variables in the first place.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: to clarify, I want to have a separete variable that is not within the structure to hold the name of the structure variable. this way, I can just change the separete variables value to the name of any of the structure variables that is within the stuct and then i would be able to use that variable (that is not the structure variable) then do `.structM` so i can accses the value stored within the member.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ does not work this way. Types are defined at runtime. They cannot be reassigned later.

You could use pointer to member of `struct`but also here the type must be known at compile time and is not exchangeable.

You cannot access a varaible indirectly by a name stored in another variable. And change it dynamically.

You could build work arounds with maps and pointers and stuff.

But it is unclear what you want to achieve. Sounds like an [X-Y-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

VTC

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to have a closer look at this external resource, which I believe offers a good explanation how to work with structs and what you can initially do.

[C++ Struct With Example](https://www.guru99.com/cpp-structures.html#5)